# Shell file is not invoking from other shell file

Tags: linux, ksh

I have a.sh and b.sh. I changed shell from bash to ksh. Now it is not invoking b.sh.

**a.sh**

```
`#!/bin/ksh
 source /home/ec2-user/env
 abc_job() {
     nohup abc >> $HOME/a.log 2>&1 </dev/null &
 }
 abc_jbo() >> $HOME/a.log
 exit 0`
```

> abc is the binary file of c that invokes b.sh

**b.sh**

```
`#!/bin/ksh
    echo "completed b.sh job >> $HOME/b.log
 exit`
```

Comment: Why do you use `ksh` ? Consider switching to [zsh](http://zsh.org/), or, if portability of your shell scripts matters, code them in POSIX `sh`

Answer (score 1):

The csh built-in command 'source' has the ksh equivalent  '.', in your case:

. /home/ec2-user/env

If execution of /home/ec2-user/env is mandatory you might want to be more defensive and verify that it is present and executable and that it completes successfully.